# How can you use Fuzzily in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I typed *fuzzily* in a spell-checked field on a website and was surprised to see it said it was correct.  I looked it up on Merriam-Webster, and sure enough [they list it as a word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fuzzy):

> **fuzz·i·ly** \ˈfə-zə-lē\ adverb

Is it possible to use the word *fuzzily* correctly in a sentence without sounding ridiculous?

Obviously the "without sounding ridiculous" being subjective, it may be hard to determine. So if ridiculousness can't be determined, can *fuzzily* be used in a sentence that is grammatically correct and the usage conveys a clear meaning?

Comment: This term is used in computing a bit, where it is termed 'fuzzy logic'. I tend to see it written more as _fuziness_, or how fuzzy something can be.

Comment: It can also be used in the same general way as _blearily_ or _groggily_ in connection with impaired sight, thinking, or remembrance. For example, from Abraham Rothberg, [_A Beast in View_](https://books.google.com/books?id=uD2Qy5c7KoQC&pg=PA176&dq=%22fuzzily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAThkahUKEwiglcXNhbnHAhXNlIgKHV5qDMA#v=onepage&q=%22fuzzily%22&f=false) (2005): "Amelia must be drunk again, old Hieronymus is mad again, I thought **fuzzily**, seeing Siva darkly dancing in the morning shadows on my mantelpiece."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eugene Lyons 1938 book *[Assignment in Utopia](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXLhwVJvfXMC&pg=PA374&dq=%22fuzzily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCWoVChMIkKDczvy4xwIVAXQ-Ch3yuA95#v=onepage&q=%22fuzzily%22&f=false)* about covering Stalinist USSR:

> It was clear on the larger objectives but **fuzzily** obscure on
>   details. Like so much of the economic planning of which he spoke, the
>   counterrevolutionary planning seemed grandiose in blueprint but
>   unrealized in practical application.

From Wallace Stegner's *[The Big Rock Candy Mountain](https://books.google.com/books?id=Je5dOcy2HF4C&pg=PA512&dq=%22fuzzily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjToozA_bjHAhXDoD4KHSrnBuk#v=onepage&q=%22fuzzily%22&f=false)*

> "It was so dark," she said **fuzzily**. "I thought everyone . . . had
>   gone."
> "Try to go back to sleep," he said. "I'll sit here with you a
>   while."

From *[Educating Liberaly](https://books.google.com/books?id=1IeaAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22fuzzily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwjToozA_bjHAhXDoD4KHSrnBuk#v=onepage&q=%22fuzzily%22&f=false)* by Hoyt H. Hudson:

> In ordinary judgments we do distinguish between a person who has at
>   command a number of facts but thinks **fuzzily** or ineptly — or to
>   unwarranted conclusions — from a man whose logic is good but who
>   builds into his logical structure proposition which deny or ignore
>   pertinent facts.

Answer (score 0):

The rusting bulwarks of Maunsell sea fort 
fuzzily looming out of  the estuary mists[image]
 Etching by Ian [Chamberlain](http://spikeprinteditions.bigcartel.com/product/fort-iii-by-ian-chamberlain) Spike Gallery Bristol UK